# Permission denied as an invited collaborator in github

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I am invited as a collaborator into a project in github. When I try to do my first push, I encounter to the following error:

```
ERROR: Permission to project/project_name.git denied to USERNEME.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I solve the issue?